# Vector not displaying full contents

Tags: c++

I have written a script so that the odd numbers are stored in a vector and then displayed at the end after putting in a negative number.

For some reason the first odd number is only displayed. Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    int val=0;
    int rem;
    vector<int>v;

    while(val>=0){
        cout<<"Please enter an integer: \n";        
        cin>>val;
        rem=val%2;
        if(rem==1)
            v.push_back(val);
        else;

    }
    for(int i=0; i<v.size(); ++i);
        cout<<"Odd Numbers: " <<v[i]<< "\n";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. Always use braces for `if`/`for` statements. 2. What is this line `else;` for?

Comment: You got some syntax errors. Disclose the **real** code.

Comment: This line `for(int i=0; i<v.size(); ++i);` is doing nothing useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating through a vector is best done with an `iterator`.

```
for(auto it = std::begin(v); it != std::end(v); it++)
    std::cout << "Odd number: " << *it << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with your semicolons:

```
for(int i=0; i<v.size(); ++i);
//                          ^^^
    cout<<"Odd Numbers: " <<v[i]<< "\n";
```

You are running the loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<v.size(); ++i) {
    ;
}
cout<<"Odd Numbers: " <<v[i]<< "\n";
```